# AOSP- How to change the permission text?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to add some text in the Permission AlertBox of the app which would appear whenever any app is asking for permission either install-time or runtime. I have explored the code in Activity.java and did not find anything in there in the requestPermission method. Can anyone help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The permission dialogs are not shown by the app or by framework classes like `Activity` linked into the app. They are shown by the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the layout of all permissions, or something similar,check **GrantPermissionsActivity.java**

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Permission/PermissionController/src/com/android/permissioncontroller/permission/ui/GrantPermissionsActivity.java

Otherwise to change labels for some specific permissions see the framework's manifest here:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. However, I noticed many cases where developers put in the description of their app on Google Play (somewhere at the bottom), the permissions the app requires along with an explanation.

Of course, there's no guarantee that all users read the app description, but, it's still a way to tell the users why do you really need those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't control the permission alert box text. On the other hand you do control what's shown before the alert box text is shown. This allows you to first explain why you need the permission to the user and then let the user set it.

Comment: I have been trying that. But the alert message is always shown under the permission alertbox. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: You can wait with requesting the Permission till the user interacted with the alert you gave him.